# Bash: Parameter expansion end of line character

Tags: bash, networking, ip, ip-address

I have a command output which follows this format (albeit with more data):

```
192.168.3.158:63402  <-> 192.168.3.1:boe-cms        0         0       1      1054       1      1054     2.000015920         0.0000
192.168.3.226:45873  <-> 192.168.2.117:boe-cms       0         0       1      1054       1      1054     2.000015840         0.0000
192.168.3.39:20224   <-> 192.168.3.55:boe-cms       0         0       1      1054       1      1054     2.000015760         0.0000
192.168.3.19:16442   <-> 192.168.2.102:boe-cms       0         0       1      1054       1      1054     2.000015680         0.0000
192.168.3.81:boe-cms <-> 192.168.3.78:4948          1      1054       0         0       1      1054     2.000015600         0.0000
192.168.3.158:8073   <-> 192.168.2.128:boe-cms       0         0       1      1054       1      1054     2.000015520         0.0000
192.168.3.247:powwow-client <-> 192.168.2.247:boe-cms       0         0       1      1054       1      1054     2.000015440         0.0000
192.168.2.212:boe-cms <-> 192.168.3.145:link         1      1054       0         0       1      1054     2.000015360         0.0000
192.168.3.165:26944  <-> 192.168.2.254:boe-cms       0         0       1      1054       1      1054     2.000015280         0.0000
192.168.2.239:boe-cms <-> 192.168.3.104:6307         1      1054       0         0       1      1054     2.000015200         0.0000
192.168.3.127:64857  <-> 192.168.3.24:boe-cms       0         0       1      1054       1      1054     2.000015120         0.0000
192.168.3.21:boe-cms <-> 192.168.3.103:856          1      1054       0         0       1      1054     2.000015040         0.0000
192.168.3.131:opendeploy <-> 192.168.2.169:boe-cms       0         0       1      1054       1      1054     2.000014960         0.0000
```

I ultimately want to parse out the IP addresses into two separate lists. This should be simple but first I want to get rid of the data after the second IP address in each line. As far as I can tell I can't treat the whitespace as columns because they're not tabs, so I tried parameter expansion starting at the 7 consecutive spaces (which signifies the end of the IP's):

```
str="${str%%"       "*}"
```

This ignores lines, and results in this output:

```
192.168.3.158:63402  <-> 192.168.3.1:boe-cms
```

So what can I change the command to to only delete until the end of the line, or what else would do the same? I've tried replacing '*' with '\n' with no luck. Thanks!

Comment: That replacement does not operate on a line-by-line basis which is why you get what you get. It trims everything after the *first* set of seven spaces. Look at [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for ways to operate on line-by-line data. First step though is **do not** stuff it all in one variable it will not help (and makes certain things much harder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk command with field separator as `:` or space to get both IP addresses:

```
awk -F '[: ]+' '{print $1, $4}' file
192.168.3.158 192.168.3.1
192.168.3.226 192.168.2.117
192.168.3.39 192.168.3.55
192.168.3.19 192.168.2.102
192.168.3.81 192.168.3.78
192.168.3.158 192.168.2.128
192.168.3.247 192.168.2.247
192.168.2.212 192.168.3.145
192.168.3.165 192.168.2.254
192.168.2.239 192.168.3.104
192.168.3.127 192.168.3.24
192.168.3.21 192.168.3.103
192.168.3.131 192.168.2.169
```

If you are getting input from a command then use:

```
command | awk -F '[: ]+' '{print $1, $4}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm also trying to preserve the port and colon though. I'm trying '{print $1, $2, $4, $5}' but it does not preserve the colon, any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Do you want `192.168.3.158:63402` in first column and `192.168.3.1:boe-cms` in 2nd column?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I'm ultimately trying to populate two arrays with those columns, one for sending IP and one for receiving.

Comment: Then you can use `awk '{print $1, $3}'`